# What is a transmission filter kit?

Tags: toyota, manual-transmission, celica

What's a transmission filter kit?

Anyway, my car has a little over 2k miles on it. I am not sure what kind of maintenance it's had in the past.

The car is a 2000 Toyota Celica GT with a manual transmission.

Comment: FYI, we don't do shopping assistance but all the other parts of the question we can assist with.  Can you edit out the price shopping component?  As well, does your car have an automatic transmission?

Comment: Either you have the most pristine 2000 Celica in existence, or you meant 200k miles?

Comment: Since we can't help with the shopping part of this, what are you actually asking here? What maintenance you should do now that it's yours? I just went through this with my Toyota and I can give you that list no problem.

Comment: This looks like a followup question based on a comment to [this question](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27277/manual-transmission-noise). It is a manual transmission, there is no filter.

Comment: @TimB  Good lookin out.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that what your asking is what maintenance should you do now that this is your car, I would suggest this list:

- Change the oil and oil filter, and use a full synthetic
- Change the fuel filter
- Change the air filters for the engine and the cabin filter if it has one. I know the Camry of that year does not, but the Celica might
- Replace the brake fluid
- Replace the coolant
- Check the power steering fluid, and replace if it's off color
- Take it to a reputable garage and get the transmission fluid changed. DO NOT use a place like Jiffy Lube.
- Check the rubber under the hood. The car is 16 years old (2000 model year was likely built in 1999) so anything rubber is going to be suspect for becoming brittle. Check every hose, look at every grommet you can without taking things apart. Where you can see the grommet look for cracks or breaks in it.
- Check the rubber under the car. In the Camry at least many of the rubber suspension bushings get old and either drop or, or loose enough to be noisy.
- Check the front and rear suspension, look for movement in the front wheels particularly that shouldn't be there. E.G. if you put the car on jack stands, so there is no weight on the front wheels, grab the top and bottom of the tire and try to move it back and forth. It should not move. Feel for slack in the motion as you turn the tires by hand. All could be bad tie rods ends, bad bearings, etc.
- Check the front and rear brakes for wear. If you replace the pads, and the rotors are close to gone anyway, might as well replace both the rotors and pads.
- Check for any codes the car might be throwing, even if the check engine light isn't on.
- Take the wheels off all 4 corners and check them for damage you might not see from the outside. When you put them back on, put anti-seize compound on them and torque them to the correct specified value. (Even Chiltons / Haynes has this number for you). Doing this on my 2000 Camry took a vibration out that was there under heavy braking.

I feel like I'm forgetting something, but this should take care of most things.

Comment: Answer not really related to transmission filters.

Comment: I answered before the question was edited, when was being asked was much less clear.  The edits were made to try and change the question into something more specific. And made my answer incorrect.